# How to access html controls in code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to follow this [example](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security/membership/validating-user-credentials-against-the-membership-user-store-cs) on how to validate credentials. However, it uses asp: controls for the login form.

If I were to use html controls instead so CSS styles can be applied, eg

```
<div id="login">
<a href="#" id="lclose"></a>

        <form action="#" runat="server">
            <fieldset>
                <div class="frame">
                    <h4>Login</h4>
                    <small>Sign in to your account.</small>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <input type="text" value="Username" class="input-text autoclear" />
                    <input type="password" value="Password" class="input-text autoclear"/>
                </div>

                <div class="separator"></div>

                <div>
                <input type="submit" value="Sign in" class="input-submit float-right" runat="server" onserverclick="LoginButton_Click"/>
                <a href="#" class="float-left">Forgot your password?</a>
                </div>

            </fieldset>
        </form>

</div>
```

How do I access the Username & Password in code behind similar to?

```
protected void LoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Validate the user against the Membership framework user store
    if (Membership.ValidateUser(UserName.Text, Password.Text))
    {
        // Log the user into the site
        FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(UserName.Text, RememberMe.Checked);
    }
    // If we reach here, the user's credentials were invalid
    InvalidCredentialsMessage.Visible = true;
}
```

What is the correct syntax instead of `UserName.Text, Password.Text`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Add `id` and `runat` server attributes to the input tag (see below)

```
<input type="text" value="Username" class="input-text autoclear"  id="Username" runat="server"/>
<input type="password" value="Password" class="input-text autoclear" id="Password" runat="server"/>
```

You also need to change `Text` to `Value` in your code:

```
protected void LoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Validate the user against the Membership framework user store
    if (Membership.ValidateUser(Username.Value, Password.Value))
    {
        // Log the user into the site
        FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(UserName.Value, RememberMe.Checked);
    }
    // If we reach here, the user's credentials were invalid
    InvalidCredentialsMessage.Visible = true;
}
```

You can also add a html `checkbox` for `RememberMe`

```
<input id="RememberMe" type="checkbox" runat="server" value ="RememberMe"/>
```

Now you can check the checked states by calling `RememberMe.Checked`

Answer (score 7):

Add runat="server" and id="your_id" and you should have access to them.  For example:

```
<input type="text" value="Username" class="input-text autoclear" 
   runat="server" id="UserName" />
<input type="password" value="Password" class="input-text autoclear" 
   runat="server" id="Password"/>
```

Then you can access the values like this:

```
Membership.ValidateUser(UserName.Value, Password.Value)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can access them from code behind by adding `runat="server"` on the html elements.

http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_refhtmlcontrols.asp

The below link has an example of how you can do this

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478973.aspx