# Get the value of a textbox in codebehind (declared using HTML in an asp.net page)

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I want to get the value of my `input` tag into my C#.

```
     <div id="datetimepicker2" class="input-append">
            <input data-format="MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss PP" type="text"></input>
            <span class="add-on">
              <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar">
              </i>
            </span>
    </div>// what should we use here?
```

The value is set by the user of the page.

Comment: which control value, you want to get?

Comment: what do you want to accomplish?

Comment: what value you are talking about?

Comment: The easiest way rather than pulling from form collections values from HTML controls, is to attribute that control with `runat="server"` and `ID="Input1"`. This makes it then a server control. Then server side it is trivial to get the value: `string textValue = this.Input1.Value;`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I did't understand which control value you want to get. But If you want to get `input` element value into the code behind, you need to set `runat="server"` attribute, because this is a simple html element not a `Asp` control.

Add runat="server" and id="your_id" and you should have access to them.

for example:

```
<input type="text" value="Username" class="input-text autoclear" 
   runat="server" id="myTextBox" />
```

than you can simply get value of input box like this:

```
string myStringFromTheInput = myTextBox.Value;
```

[For more options please See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16875238/how-to-access-html-controls-in-code-behind)

Answer (score 3):

Try this

Add name for your input type

```
 <input data-format="MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss PP" name="txtBox1" type="text"></input>
```

and try this way for get value in codebehind

```
string value=Request.Form["txtBox1"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access all your submitted form data at server side by looking into the form Request object.

Ex. `Request.Form["txtDate"]` OR `Request["txtDate"]`.

*Naming the html elements makes easier to look into form collection for specified element.*

Answer (score -2):

If what you posted is your actual code, you have an extra space in your closing tag

```
</asp: TextBox>
```

Should be

```
</asp:TextBox>
```

and then txt_todata.text should work

Comment: The OP want to get input text (html control values not a asp.net control value)