# How can I find out if a check box is checked?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have 3 check boxes and I would like to write a statement in C# that will allow me to find out which of the boxes is checked. I tried using

```
 if(check1.IsChecked.Value == 1){
}
```

But that didnt seem to work. How can I solve this? I would also like to be able to get the text belonging to the checked check box. Here is the HTML code for the check boxes.

```
<div>
       <h3>Membership Type</h3>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="radio" value="1" name="check1" />Normal User</label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="radio" value="1" name="check2" />Verified Reviewer</label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="radio" value="1" name="check3" />Development Team</label>

        </div>
```

Comment: Where are you exactly trying to access the checkbox? Remember, C# runs on the server side and HTML on the client side. You won't have access to the checkbox unless the page gets posted back.

Comment: In what way "did it not work"?

Comment: You don´t need to to use the .Value == 1, just use if(check1.IsChecked)

Comment: Downvoting because of missing information. You do not make clear whether that is pure HTML or hosted in some ASP.NET page/view

Comment: Also, as @PoweredByOrange noted, you'll need to include your HTML Checkbox in a form to postback and get the value there.

Comment: @sab669 I just got an error saying "the name 'check1" does not exist in the current context."

Comment: How are you accessing that HTML?

Comment: @cfrozendeath This is on an ASP.NET page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access html controls in code behind](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16875238/how-to-access-html-controls-in-code-behind)

Comment: If it's an ASP.NET page, why not just use an ASP checkbox control instead  of a "basic" HTML input?

Comment: MVC? Webforms? Do you have a <form> element anywhere?

Comment: @Swailem95 If this is an ASP.NET page, use an ASP.NET checkbox: `<asp:CheckBox ID="check1" runat="server"/>` that way you can access it in the code behind.

Comment: You need to add runat="server" to access html generic controls in the code behind. But as @PoweredByOrange suggested use the ASP checkbox control.

Comment: @Poweredbyorange Alright great, I did that. How can I find out if any of them are checked in C#?

Comment: @Swailem95 `check1.Checked` and so on. See the documentation on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkbox(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell if you are expecting a radio button style, where only one option is available at a time, or checkbox style which would allow any combination of selections.  This may be what you are after:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblUserType" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Normal User" Value="1" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Verified Reviewer" Value="2" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Development Team" Value="3" />
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Code side:

```
if (rblUserType.SelectedIndex == 1)
{
    //First value selected
}
else if (rblUserType.SelectedValue == "2")
{
    //An alternate way to select which entry was selected
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Only the ID of a .Net control is mapped to a variable, the name is not. Assign a value to the ID tag parameter and use runat="server" to be able to access it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have check boxes as HTML control. You cant access those in c# code behind. Instead you can use javascript code to get text of selected checkbox or mark the control as runat=Server

Comment: Could you put an example code about what have you explained?